# Find all Database Objects by Name?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I find all database objects in a given database using an object name?  We prefix all site specific tables, views, indexes, functions, constraints etc. with a constant string.  I need to find all objects with names starting with that string.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Assuming you have the right permissions:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourdatabasename.sys.all_objects
WHERE upper(name) like upper('my prefix%')  --use UPPER for case-INsensitivity
```